# Github service hook for community translation webservice

Tags: android, github, localization, pootle

I am taking care of an open source project: [mixare](http://www.mixare.org). It's an augmented reality browser released under the GPLv3.

The source code of the project is on [github](https://github.com/mixare/mixare) and I would like to hook the localization part to some web-service a-la [pootle](http://translate.sourceforge.net/wiki/pootle/index). If necessary I can install my own instance of a translation service on our server, but also an hosted solution would be fine. So I would like to know:

Is there a preferred translation web service that syncs using github's service hooks? Any best practice to share?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I know that getlocalization.com is among the supported translation services, but it's not clear to me whether they allow free software projects. I would appreciate if someone can comment also wrt this aspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git integration is one of major reasons why I started to write [Weblate](http://weblate.org/). It also supports [remote trigger for git pull using URL](http://weblate.readthedocs.org/en/latest/admin.html#interacting-with-others), so it nicely integrates with Github (you just need to put the URL there).

PS: I've just noticed that Android string resources are not supported by backend I use for loading translations (translate toolkit), so it probably won't work for you...

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately Android isn't using po/mo files :( I was hoping to be able to use it as soon as I've seen your blogpost on planet Debian, since I would really really prefer to use a free software solution!

Comment: I don't think it would be hard to add support for Android string resources to translate toolkit (at least to level what Weblate needs). I will try to ook at it sometimes.

Comment: And indeed it was not that hard, see http://blog.cihar.com/archives/2012/04/20/weblate-gets-experimental-support-android-resource/

Comment: Awesome @Michal! I shared it from the mixare g+ page: https://plus.google.com/b/112059518295078178208/112059518295078178208/posts/CGxLU7n5Hds . I'm eager to test this!

Answer (score 1):

While I appreciate your wish for git support, shouldn't you primarily be looking for a solution that will give you many and good translations?

To get many translations I'd recommend [Translatewiki](http://translatewiki.net), unfortunately their manual setup takes some time though.

Apart from Translatewiki, [transifex](http://transifex.com) seems to be one of the better and not least bigger (counting translators) services. They've made their own client that take care of importing and merging translations. For `gettext` translations it can also pull in updated template (pot) files automatically from github, I don't know if that's also possible with Android style translations.

Both Translatewiki and Transifex are 100% free and open source software.

Answer (score 0):

I've been through the same "nothing good out there" phase, so I've started writing my own, as a symfony2 bundle. Maybe it's of use to you: https://github.com/tvogt/translator-bundle

Why? Because I couldn't get weblate or pootle to work, you probably have to be familiar with all the pip and python and ve and whatever stuff. Translatewiki is only for free software. Transifix is commercial.

Answer (score 0):

In 2020, with [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) (hooks executed on GitHub side), you now have [GitLocalize](https://github.com/marketplace/gitlocalize)

> GitLocalize is a continuous localization tool built for communities and teams that want to simplify their workflow when translating their content.

> GitLocalize automatically keeps translations up to date by syncing with your repository.

That won't apply to the OP's project [`github.com/mixare/mixare`](https://github.com/mixare/mixare), which was moved to GitLab in 2018.
But it can help other projects with a similar need.

Answer (score -1):

You can have a look at [Amanuens](http://amanuens.com) - it's able to sync with any Git repository, including Github. It's totally free for open-source projects (contact support for details). Disclaimer: it is my company's service.

Comment: According to their website, the service has been discontinued.